# Run pocketsphinx_continuous with a keyphrase

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am trying to use a keyphrase with pocketsphinx, but it keeps throwing the error,

```
ERROR: "kws_search.c", line 171: The word 'hey' is missing in the dictionary
```

Even though it is 100% in the dictionary. It is a big part of the dictionary and it recognizes that word fine when I leave the keyphrase out. Am I using it wrong? There isn't a tutorial that I could find. Everything is using python or android.

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us -dict 9063.dic -lm 9063.lm -vad_threshold 3.0 -kws keyphrase.file -infile /dev/stdin
```

and the keyphrase.file is

```
hey /1.0/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct command line is:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -vad_threshold 3.0 -kws keyphrase.file -infile /dev/stdin
```

you do not need `-lm` and `-dict` which configures language model search mode. You need keyword search mode. When you use `-dict` you replace default dictionary with the dictionary with upper-case words. Words are case sensitive.

Tutorial is [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm).

Comment: The difference between lm and keywords is that the latter use threshold to listen continuously and report matches. The former always try to detect something from the lm.